# how to start console application with windows application and read (monitoring) command line - line by line real time in c#

Tags: winforms, console, console-application, command-line-interface

I have a console application which generating rows line by line:
Data1
Data2
Data3
...
and when its over command line will be cleared, it reapeats infinitelly (the datas can change)
I have to watch the console application's command line with windows aplication real time and work for the lines data (for example save it to list ox line by line)! It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to subscribe to the output streams of that console application, to be able to get each line printed on the console.

What you need to do is to create the Windows Forms application (WPF would also work) and start the console application from there.

If you don't want to show your current console application as a visible window, remember to set CreateNoWindow to true.

Here's how to start the console application:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments);
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // We handle the output
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // If you want to hide the console application so it only works in the background.

// Create the actual process
currentProcess = new Process();
currentProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
currentProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

// Start the process
bool processDidStart = currentProcess.Start();
```

We need a BackgroundWorker to read the output from the console application in the background.

```
outputReader = TextReader.Synchronized(currentProcess.StandardOutput);
outputWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Now you're able to get all the output from the console application in real time and use it to create a list or whatever you want to.

```
void outputWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Work until cancelled
    while (outputWorker.CancellationPending == false)
    {
        int count = 0;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        do
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            // Read the data from the buffer and append to the StringBuilder
            count = outputReader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            builder.Append(buffer, 0, count);

            outputWorker.ReportProgress(0, new OutputEvent() { Output = builder.ToString() });
        } while (count > 0);
    }
}
```

The processed data is available through the ProgressChanged event of the BackgroundWorker.

```
void outputWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.UserState is OutputEvent)
    {
        var outputEvent = e.UserState as OutputEvent;

        /* HERE YOU CAN USE THE OUTPUT LIKE THIS:
         * outputEvent.Output
         *
         * FOR EXAMPLE:
         * yourList.Add(outputEvent.Output);
         */
    }
}
```

The above code is taken and modified to your purposes from the following Codeproject.com article in case it ceases to exist in the future: [Embedding a Console in a C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application).

Comment: Thx for your answer, I have a problem when i start the program my console application throw a windows error message: the program has stopped working.... 
But if i start the console application like this: Process.Start("myconsolapp.exe") then its working but in this way i cant catch the command line datas

Comment: @LaszloBOZSAR Does your main application crash or is it the console app that's crashing?

Comment: Console app is crashing, because there is a Console.Clear command in it if i get out it it's ok but if i use it it's not working

Comment: @LaszloBOZSAR It sounds like when we redirect the output stream, it messes with the `Console.Clear` command. `Console.Clear` fills the screen buffer with blank characters internally so most likely our output streaming implementation stops it from working. A very dirty "fix" would be to write newlines until the screen is empty and ignore it in the main application. Anyway, if you feel like your question is answered, feel free to mark it as such.